# defining repr() of classes (not instances)

Tags: python, class, debugging, instance

I have a bunch of classes which I'm using as singletons / enums / dict keys, e. g. like this:

```
class Side(object): pass

class Left(Side): pass
class Right(Side): pass

def show_state(distribution):
    print "left is", distribution[Left]
    print "right is", distribution[Right]

distribution = { Left: 3, Right: 7 }
show_state(distribution)
```

This works fine for me.  But I'm having a small issue with debug output I sometimes do.  Normally I use just `print` for this like in `print distribution` in the `show_state()` function.  I would love to have an output like:

```
{ Left: 3, Right: 7 }
```

But when I do this with these classes they are given out as something like this:

```
{<class '__main__.Right'>: 7, <class '__main__.Left'>: 3}
```

I tried to override the `__repr__()` method of my classes to achieve this, but when I do it only influences *instances* of my classes (which I never create).  I tried to use `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` but nothing worked.

I assume that what I print is a `Left` and therefore an instance of `<type 'type'>`, so I would have to override the `__repr__()` method of the `type` class which is immutable, unfortunately.

Is there any other trick I could use so that `print distribution` would print what I want?

Btw, according to the documentation, the `__repr__()` method should return something which the Python parser would turn into an equal object again; this is definitely not the case with an output like `<class '__main__.Right'>` but would definitely be the case with an output like `Right`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct that you'd have to override the `__repr__` of the type of a class; you don't need to edit `type`, you'd *subclass* `type` to create a [new metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses):

```
class SimpleRepr(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return cls.__name__
```

then use that as your class metaclass; assuming you are using Python 3:

```
class Side(metaclass=SimpleRepr): pass
```

or if you are using Python 2 still:

```
class Side(object):
    __metaclass__ = SimpleRepr
```

Subclasses of `Side` inherit the metaclass too:

```
>>> class SimpleRepr(type):
...     def __repr__(cls):
...         return cls.__name__
...
>>> class Side(metaclass=SimpleRepr): pass
...
>>> class Left(Side): pass
...
>>> class Right(Side): pass
...
>>> { Left: 3, Right: 7 }
{Left: 3, Right: 7}
```

However, you could just have used instances:

```
class Side(object):
    __slots__ = ('name',)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

Left = Side('Left')
Right = Side('Right')
```

Comment: And I guess you could save a few bytes by defining `__slots__`

Comment: Sure, but I was referring to the 2nd version, where you do create instances.

Comment: @PM2Ring: not that it makes all that much difference across 2 objects, though.

Comment: True, it's not like they're creating lots of instances.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!  The instances version works only for unstructured subclasses.  In fact I want to have stuff like Left, Right, Front, Back, and derived stuff like FrontLeft (inheriting Front and Left) etc.  So I will try the first version :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an Enum with **repr**

```
from enum import Enum

class Side(Enum):
  Left = 'Left'
  Right = 'Right'

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.name


distribution = { Side.Left: 3, Side.Right: 7 }

print distribution  # {Right: 7, Left: 3}
```

Comment: I'd have the `__repr__` return `'{}.{}'.format(self.__class__, self.__name__)` in that case, but otherwise good idea!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. OP s requirement is just to print the name of the side.

Comment: Not *quite*. They want to show the same Python expression as was used to create the dictionary in the first place. In the case of an Enum, that's `Side.Left`, not `Left`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Make sense. I'll leave my answer as such and OP will get the idea anyway from your comments. Thanks.

Comment: Enums are not suiting me in all aspects here.  I want to have an inheritance tree below Side: Left, Right, Front, Back, and then stuff like FrontLeft which inherits two of the other.  That's not possible with mere enums.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're finding this difficult is that this is a strange use of classes, really. Have you considered just having one class, Side, and having left and right as instances?

```
class Side(object):
    def __init__(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.direction

left = Side(left)
right = Side(right)
```